# How to summarise the values of xslt function which are returned by it

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Hello everybody
My Problem is that  i cannot summarise values between the nodes that do not equal "skip". 
[image]

My output should be something like this:

```
6
6
```

Here is my html
data

```
<html xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0" xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0" xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0" xmlns:style="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0" xmlns:draw="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:drawing:1.0" xmlns:fo="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:number="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:datastyle:1.0" xmlns:svg="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:svg-compatible:1.0" xmlns:of="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:of:1.2" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <body>
      <h1>example_2</h1>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <td>name_of_file</td>
            <td>global_structure in a code_1</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>global_structure in a code_2</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>name of the file</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>skip</td>
            <td>text_var</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>funktion</td>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>skip</td>
            <td>;</td>
            <td>;</td>
            <td>funktion</td>
            <td>A2</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>skip</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>var</td>
            <td>A2_var</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>skip</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>funktion</td>
            <td>A3</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>skip</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>var</td>
            <td>A3_var</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>skip</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>;</td>
            <td>;</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>name of the file_2</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>skip</td>
            <td>text_var</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>funktion</td>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>skip</td>
            <td>;</td>
            <td>;</td>
            <td>funktion</td>
            <td>A2</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>skip</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>var</td>
            <td>A2_var</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>skip</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>funktion</td>
            <td>A3</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>skip</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>var</td>
            <td>A3_var</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>skip</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>;</td>
            <td>;</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>end</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
   </html>
```

And my xslt code:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0" xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0" xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0" xmlns:style="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0" xmlns:draw="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:drawing:1.0" xmlns:fo="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:number="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:datastyle:1.0" xmlns:svg="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:svg-compatible:1.0" xmlns:of="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:of:1.2" office:version="1.2"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:mf="http://userfunctions.com/functions"
extension-element-prefixes="mf">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>


  <xsl:template match="/html/body/table/tr">
    <xsl:variable name="number_of_lines_var"  select="mf:number_of_lines()"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="$number_of_lines_var"/>
  </xsl:template>


<xsl:function name="mf:number_of_lines" as="xs:integer">



  <xsl:sequence  

     select="if (./td[1] ='skip')

             then $number_of_lines_var+1

             else $number_of_lines_var"
             />

</xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But only thing I get is error :

*Variable number_of_lines_var has not been declared (or its declaration is not in scope)*

Inside the function scope, how is it possible to ovveride the variable outside the *xsl:function*?
Are there any other soultions to calculate the number of nodes with "skip" between the nodes that do not equal "skip"
Thanks in advance
P.S. The same code is here:
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bwe3c5/43

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `group-starting-with` it is also possible to use `group-adjacent`:

```
  <xsl:function name="mf:skip-sequences" as="xs:integer*">
      <xsl:param name="table" as="element(table)"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="$table/tr" group-adjacent="boolean(self::tr[td[1] = 'skip'])">
          <xsl:sequence select="count(current-group())[current-grouping-key()]"/>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="table">
      <xsl:sequence select="mf:skip-sequences(.)"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hello Martin, I have a question about usage of <xsl:sequence select="count(current-group())[current-grouping-key()]"/> I cannot understand for which purpose is current-grouping-key() used.

Comment: It is used in the predicate to ensure the count is only returned for the groups of  `tr` skip elements.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error message means that you can't declare a variable in one template or function, and then access it in another. In that respect, XSLT is like many other conventional programming languages: a variable has a static scope, which is essentially the instructions that follow the variable declaration, within the same template or function.

And the solution to that would normally be to pass the value of the variable as a parameter to the function.

But now I get really confused by what you're trying to achieve, because you initialise the variable by calling the function:

```
<xsl:variable name="number_of_lines_var"  select="mf:number_of_lines()"/>
```

and then in the function you try and access the value of the variable

```
<xsl:function name="mf:number_of_lines" as="xs:integer">
  <xsl:sequence  
     select="if (...) then ... else $number_of_lines_var/>
</xsl:function>
```

which seems completely circular.

Trying to work out what you might have been thinking when you wrote this, perhaps you imagined that calling the function would increment the value of the variable? If that's so, then I'm afraid you've completely misunderstood how functional languages work. Functions don't have side-effects, and variables don't change their value.

The solution to your problem, I think, is completely different, and looks something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="td" group-starting-with="*[td[1] ne 'skip']">
  <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())-1"/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

You'll need to refine that a bit to deal with the header and trailer rows in the table, but I'll leave that to you because you know more about the data than I do.